# mysqldump doesn't create tables or import any data

Tags: mysql, import

I am trying to import a mysqldump into a new database.  When I run:

`mysqldump -umydbuser -p --database testimport < database.dump`

I get the following output:

```
Enter password:
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: testimport
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.0.75-0ubuntu10.3

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `testimport`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `testimport` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET     latin1 */;

USE `testimport`;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2010-03-09 17:46:03
```

However, when I look at the testimport database, there are no tables and no data.  Even if I export a working database by:

`mysqldump -umydbuser -p --database workingdatabase > test.sql`

and then import:

`mysqldump -umydbuser -p --database testimport < test.sql`

I get the same output, but nothing is imported into the `testimport` database.  I don't see any errors in the output and it is using the proper database.  If I tail the exported .sql file, I see the create statements for all tables and the inserts for all data.  Why isn't this data importing?  Is there any additional logging I can see?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You want to run the dump through the mysql client.

Example:

`mysql -uroot -p testimport < database.dump`

Comment: Different tools for different purposes, Josh.

Comment: It worked, but what is the difference please?

Answer (score 11):

Because when you dump data (Backup) you used "mysqldump" :

```
mysqldump -u user -p Database_name > SQL_dump_file.sql
```

But when restore data into database you need to use only "mysql":

```
mysql -u user -p Database_name < SQL_dump_file.sql
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, just export de DDL (only structure) and export full database, then import first the DDL file, next import the full file using the same sentence

```
mysqldump -uroot -p 'database' < 'filename.sql'
```

Comment: You can't import data with `mysqldump`, it's an export only tool. `mysql` is for import.